# Async method running too fast to update my listbox on the main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, iprogress

I have a WPF button and a list box. when I press the button, it uses async and await to run a number generator. The number generator is just a for loop producing integers. Also in the loop is a Iprogress reporting the integer. A function in the main thread, updates the listBox in the UI.

The problem is that the listbox is not updated correctly, however if I put a Thread.sleep(10) in the for loop , it works fine. Looks like the thread is generating reports too fast for the listbox to update.How can I do away with the Thread.sleep(10) and update the listbox faithfully? Am I approaching this the correct way? Can someone please help? Thanks.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Progress<ProgressReportModel> progress = new Progress<ProgressReportModel>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progress.ProgressChanged += ReportProgress;
    }   
    private async void generateNumbersButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>NumberGenerator.SimpleNumberGenerator(progress));
    }
    private void ReportProgress(object sender, ProgressReportModel e)
    {
        numbersListBox.Items.Add($"Integer generated {e.LastIntegerGenerated.ToString()}");
    }
}


static class NumberGenerator
{
    static public void SimpleNumberGenerator(IProgress<ProgressReportModel> progress)
    {
        ProgressReportModel report = new ProgressReportModel();
        int number = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i <= number ; i++)
        {
            report.LastIntegerGenerated = i;
            progress.Report(report);
            //Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}

public class ProgressReportModel
{
    public int LastIntegerGenerated { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

[run with no Thread.Sleep in the loop. Expecting integers 0 to 10 but getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ5tV.png)

[run with Thread.Sleep(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzT3S.png)

[run with Thread.Sleep(10) and it the numbers are registered faithfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOCj1.png)

Comment: The links aren't relevant. You don't need to put `Thread.Sleep` in the *reporting* thread.

Comment: Any time that someone says "I used a random number generator and it worked fine when I run the code slowly [like stepping a debugger] but when I run full speed prod code it doesnt work!" I instantly jump to wondering "are you seeding your RNG from the clock?" - plenty of Qs here where someone declared new Random() in a loop and didnt realise that for about 1000 loop iterations in a row the code was faster than the clock resolution, so the RNG was seeded with the same time value, clobbering the randomness

Comment: Both WinForms and WPF controls support data binding. Instead of explicitly adding an item to a listbox, bind the listbox to a container of data to display, eg `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`. Add the data to that container and let the UI update itself. Redrawing the UI in a tight loop is expensive though, so you may want to throttle the redraw operations somehow.

Comment: Running this `Task` (a task in general in this case) is irrelevant as well, you're abusing async/await , ask yourself if you really need another thread... JMHO.

Comment: The problem in this code is caused precisely because you try to modify the UI in a tight loop. The UI code has no chance to complete before another event is fired. You're redrawing too frequently, not reporting too fast.

Comment: You are posting and modifing the same ProgressReportModel instance ... So obviously if program hits ReportProgress it may have different value then when it was posted

Comment: I just realized the question never explained what's wrong. I didn't notice the *same* instance is used in all `Report` calls. This means the *same* object is added multiple times to the listbox, resulting in identical values in the listbox. Too frequent redrawing is a problem, but reporting the *wrong* values is worse.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the problem is that the ReportProgress method is getting called *after* the LastIntegerGenerated property of your report object gets updated.

The simplest way to fix the problem is to use a new report object for each call to progress.Report.  Move the line:

```
ProgressReportModel report = new ProgressReportModel();
```

to be within your for loop, and you should no longer need to put that delay in.

Comment: [Progress<T>](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) is a fundamental .NET BCL class used to report progress from asynchronous operations in a thread-safe manner